# how to get random characters in a variable on button click?

Tags: php, html

here is my code that generates random characters

How can i get this random characters when i click my button 'submit' . and get that as a variable to save on database. please help

this is my button

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" name="submit">POST</button>
</span>
```

this generates random characters

```
<?php
$result = "";

$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
$chararray = str_split($chars);
for($i = 0; $i < 7 ; $i++){
    $randitem = array_rand($chararray);
    $result .= "".$chararray[$randitem];
}

echo $result;
?>
```

i want to get that random character as a variable like `$post_randomid = $_POST[random_id];`

Comment: where is your form

Comment: here just help me to get that random id  when i click that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['rand'])) {
        echo $_POST['rand'];
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST" >
    //this generates random characters
    <?php
    $result = "";
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    $chararray = str_split($chars);
    for($i = 0; $i < 7 ; $i++){
    $randitem = array_rand($chararray);
    $result .= "".$chararray[$randitem];
    }
    echo $result;
    // i want to get that random character as a variable like  $post_randomid =$_POST[random_id];
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result;?>" name="rand" />
    //this is my button
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" name="submit">POST</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks arun it works  but can you help me to insert in database ?

Comment: how can  i  insert that $result value in databese 

$insert ="insert into table (rand_id) values ('$result' ) ";

Comment: my reputation is not 15 yet so i am unable to vote.... i   will as soon as i reach their

Answer (score 0):

Send the value either in the session on the server or create a hidden input type on the client. The second option solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $result = "";

    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    $chararray = str_split($chars);
    for($i = 0; $i < 7 ; $i++){
            $randitem = array_rand($chararray);
            $result .= "".$chararray[$randitem];
    }
    ?>

    <form action="my_php_database_script.php" method="POST">
            <input name="chars" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit">POST</button>
    </form>
```

You could access your result with $_POST["chars"] in your script php (*my_php_database_script.php*) to save it in database.

If you want to do it asynchronously without leaving this page, you have to deal with AJAX.